# Скрыть/показать форму OnVisibleChanged

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня переопределен метод `OnVisibleChanged`:

```
protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

т.е, при загрузке программы - форма сразу скрывается.

Как мне потом вызвать этот же метод, но только наоборот, чтобы форму показало?

Пробовал так:

```
this.Show();
this.Visible = true;
```

Все тщетно, ну, оно и понятно, ведь вызывается `OnVisibleChanged`, а у него `false` стоит.

Скрывать/показывать форму через `Hide/Show` мне не подходят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменяя видимость в функции реагирующей на на изменение видимости формы не правильно. Нужно перенести ваш код из `OnVisibleChanged` куда нибудь еще, например в `OnLoad`. А код @altexoander использовать в какой либо функции (кроме `OnVisibleChanged`).

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...  // Что то еще.
    this.Visible = false;
}

public void ChangeVisible()
{
    this.Visible = this.Visible ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Или код не рабочий, или я туплю. Сделал всё как вы написали, при запуске - форма НЕ скрывается, а потом (через секунду) вылетает ошибка (не на ваши строки, а на "ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.")

Comment: @Максим WPF или Winforms?

Comment: сорри что так долго, Winforms.

Comment: @Максим, значит смотрите. В форме которую будем скрывать ищем, в свойствах, событие `Load` и дважды на нем щелкаем. Переходим в код формы, в конкретный обработчик события и дописываем в него `'this.Visible = false;`. Удаляем все художества из `OnVisibleChanged`, сам обработчик не трогаем (получаем пустую функцию). В классе формы дописываем ПУБЛИЧНУЮ функцию `ChangeVisible`. Теперь мы можем из другой формы, запустить эту форму в скрытом виде, и управлять ее видимостью (не забудьте только подписаться на Form.Deactivate)

Comment: В Form_Load, this.Visible = false; не скрывает форму.

Comment: @Максим, не надо тупо копировать весь код, найдите функцию обрабатывающую `Load` и просто скопируйте туда эту строку.

Comment: я так и делал как вы написали. Попробуйте сами скрыть форму this.Visible = false; в Load - не получится, НО как только я повесил this.Visible = false; на секундный таймер, вроде заработало правильно, сейчас сижу проверяю.

Comment: @Максим, я думаю вы что то накрутили в остальном коде, на чистом окне, отлично работает

Comment: Только что на чистом проверил еще раз, нифига не работает. А вы проверяли? =) Или вы просто уверены что работает?)

Comment: @Максим, естественно проверил, ищите ощибки

Comment: В общем, спасибо большое за помощь ВСЕМ, вроде работает правильно, но в Load всё равно форму не скрывает :)

Answer (score 2):

Проверяй состояние видимости формы и просто поменяй код. Например , у тебя сейчас

`this.Visible = false`

Кто тебе мешает проверить и поставить такое?

```
protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    this.Visible = this.Visible ? false : true;
}
```

Т.е. на каждый вызов VisibleChanged ты просто будешь игнорировать внешние вызовы и поочередно менять видимость с true на false ( например 2умя вызовами .Show форма покажется и спряется вновь).

Красоты маловато, но это решение "влоб".

Comment: Всё равно не показывает форму.

Comment: @Mirdin, эм, не совсем понял. Как это для отображения формы нужно делать this.Visible = false ? Ну, в любом случае не работает.

Comment: @Максим, к сожалению даже это не сработает, так как функция зациклится, изменяя видимость формы, мы вызываем `OnVisibleChanged`. Свой комментарий я поэтому удалил.

Comment: @Максим а каким образом ты пытаешься изменить видимость формы? Просто я теряюсь в догадках почему у тебя не происходит изменений.

Comment: @alexoander, вы же, сейчас, поправили немного код? При использовании, если я не ошибаюсь, тернарного оператора в OnVisibleChanged, при запуске приложения выскакивает ошибка: Необработанное исключение типа "System.StackOverflowException" в System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: @alexoander она зацикливается, поэтому надо использовать другую функцию

Comment: Воу , я понял - спасибо что рассказали=) Можно еще попробовать базовое поведение вызывать **после** смены Visible.